# AWS ECS describe-task-definition doesn't return EFS file system specification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cli, amazon-efs

I tried with

```
aws ecs describe-task-definition --task-definition task1
```

but only get the volume names

```
...,
"volumes": [{
     "name": "test1"
}], ...
```

According to [spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/efs-volumes.html) I should receive an `efsVolumeConfiguration` object inside each `volume`, too. Does anyone know why I can't see the information or how I otherwise can retrieve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: They don't have anything other than `name`? I believe that means they are local ephemeral storage, not EFS. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html

Comment: Forgot to mention: test1 is indeed an efs mount.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue.

Had to upgrade my aws cli to version `aws-cli/2.0.58`, now it get the `efsVolumeConfiguration`.